# EF-Model for many-to-many Junction Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.2, ef-model-builder

I'm trying to straighten out the EF-Model for a junctiontable OwnerCows.dbo.
There's a class Cow with an Id, a class Owner with an Id and i want to reference them both in a OwnerCows-table that has only an OwnerCowId, a CowId(FK) and a OwnerId(FK).

The error I'm getting is:
Cannot create a relationship between 'Owner.OwnerCows' and 'OwnerCow.Owner', because there already is a relationship between 'Owner.CowOwners' and 'OwnerCow.Owner'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

Does it mean I have a circular reference? How can I solve this?

the Owner.cs:

```
public class Owner : EntityBase<Guid>
  {

   public string Name { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public ICollection<Cow> Cows { get; set; }
     = new List<Cow>();

   public virtual List<OwnerCow> CowOwners { get; set; }
   public Cow Cow { get; set; }

   }
```

the Cow.cs:

```
public class Cow : EntityBase<Guid>
{ 
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }         

    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Color {  get; set; }

    public ICollection<Entities.Weight> Weights { get; set; }
      = new List<Weight>();
    public ICollection<Vaccination> Vaccinations { get; set; }
      = new List<Vaccination>();

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Owner> CowOwners { get; set; }
     = new List<Owner>();
    public List<OwnerCow> OwnerCows { get; set; }

}
```

the OwnerCows.cs:

```
public class OwnerCow 
{
    public Guid OwnerCowId { get; set; }
    public Cow Cow { get; set; }
    public Guid CowId { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

the Context-class:

```
    public class DogFaceContext : DbContext
    {
      public DogFaceContext()
      {

      }
      public DogFaceContext(DbContextOptions<DogFaceContext> options)
        : base(options)
      {
        Database.Migrate();          
      }

      //Entity Tables
      public virtual DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Cow> Cows { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Vaccination> Vaccination { get; set; }
      public virtual DbSet<Weight> Weight { get; set; }

      //Junction Tables
      public virtual DbSet<OwnerCow> OwnerCows { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
      {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Cow>().HasMany(x => x.CowOwners).WithOne(x => x.Cow);
        builder.Entity<Owner>().HasMany(u => u.CowOwners).WithOne(X => X.Owner);

        builder.Entity("DogFace.API.Entities.OwnerCow", b =>
        {
          b.HasOne("DogFace.API.Entities.Cow", "Cow")
          .WithMany("OwnerCows")
          .HasForeignKey("CowId")
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

         b.HasOne("DogFace.API.Entities.Owner", "Owner")
         .WithMany("OwnerCows")
         .HasForeignKey("OwnerId")
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });
      }
   }
```

[image: EF-Model]
Can I get it to work with this design? Is it possible with EFCore? Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of the last 2 `builder.Entity` with string parameters? They seem wrong and are causing the exception. Just remove them and put the additional configuration (if needed) on the first 2 typed relationship configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You model is very complex and has some unnecessary relationships like Owner.Cows since you decide to configure many-to-many relationship.You could just get Owner's cows using

```
var owner = new Owner();
List<Cow> cows = owner.OwnerCows.Where(oc => oc.OwnerId == owner.Id)
                       .Select(oc => oc.Cow)
                       .ToList();
```

1.To have OwnerCowId, a CowId(FK) and a OwnerId(FK) in OwnerCows, refer to my below configuration:

```
public class Owner : EntityBase<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }   

    public virtual List<OwnerCow> OwnerCows { get; set; }
}

public class Cow : EntityBase<Guid>
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entities.Weight> Weights { get; set; } = new List<Weight>();
    public ICollection<Vaccination> Vaccinations { get; set; }= new List<Vaccination>();

    public List<OwnerCow> OwnerCows { get; set; }

}

public class OwnerCow
{
    [Key]
    public Guid OwnerCowId { get; set; }
    public Cow Cow { get; set; }
    public Guid CowId { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<OwnerCow>()
                .HasOne(oc => oc.Cow)
                .WithMany(c => c.OwnerCows)
                .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.CowId);
        builder.Entity<OwnerCow>()
            .HasOne(oc => oc.Owner)
            .WithMany(o => o.OwnerCows)
            .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.OwnerId);

    }
}
```

In this case, your `OwnerCowId` id the primary key for your `OwnerCows` table which is not reasonable and it may have the same record of CowId,OwnerId for OwnerCows.

2.Usually,the primary key for the join table is a composite key comprising both of the foreign key values,I suggest that you could use composite key for your `OwnerCow`:

```
public class OwnerCow
{
    public Cow Cow { get; set; }
    public Guid CowId { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);


        builder.Entity<OwnerCow>()
               .HasKey(oc => new { oc.OwnerId, oc.CowId });
        builder.Entity<OwnerCow>()
                .HasOne(oc => oc.Cow)
                .WithMany(c => c.OwnerCows)
                .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.CowId);
        builder.Entity<OwnerCow>()
            .HasOne(oc => oc.Owner)
            .WithMany(o => o.OwnerCows)
            .HasForeignKey(oc => oc.OwnerId);

    }
}
```

Refer to https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Fix context builder:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Cow>().HasMany(x => x.CowOwners).WithOne(x => x.Cow);
    builder.Entity<Owner>().HasMany(u => u.Cows).WithOne(X => X.Owner); // Cows instead of CowOwners

    builder.Entity("DogFace.API.Entities.OwnerCow", b =>
    {
      b.HasOne("DogFace.API.Entities.Cow", "Cow")
      .WithMany("OwnerCows")
      .HasForeignKey("CowId")
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

     b.HasOne("DogFace.API.Entities.Owner", "Owner")
     .WithMany("CowOwners") // CowOwners instead of OwnerCows
     .HasForeignKey("OwnerId")
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    });
  }
```

... or fix property names in classes:

```
public class Owner : EntityBase<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Cow> CowOwners { get; set; } // CowOwners instead of Cows ?
        = new List<Cow>();

    public virtual List<OwnerCow> OwnerCow { get; set; } // OwnerCow instead  of CowOwners ?
    public Cow Cow { get; set; }
}
```

but don't forget to change dbcontext builder with fixed property names.